# Cannot save music files on iPhone iOS5

Tags: iphone

I had installed and updated the libimobiledevice, and now, ubuntu can see my iphone after connected. Great to have this libimobile device tool.

From Banshee or Rhythmbox, can see music in my iPhone. 
But,the music files only can move one way. I cannot save the music files into the iPhone. Only the music files can be copied out from iPhone into the harddrive of ubuntu.

What's wrong with my setup? Or this is the bottleneck of current libimobiledevice?
Thanks for your advice.